# Excel function to organize and classify behavioural data

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a table that I have to use in order to classify the different behaviours from cattle depending on the time that they spend doing certain activities.
For example: If an animal spent 5 ocnsecutive minutes standing without any motion index or steps i have to classify this behaviour as Resting. If the animal spend more than 30 seconds standing I have to classify the behaviour as standing for that minute, same for lying.

Is there a function to classify, by analyzing 5 rows (row=minutes) so If an animal spent 5 minutes standing without motion index or steps I have to classify it as resting, is there any way to do a function for it on excel?

[image]

I tried this formula, however it is classifying resting behaviour as standing.
Here is the link for you guys to check the excell file with the formula.

https://1drv.ms/x/s!AtN4xlQTB4pPkTIOIUWYj5MzUnAe?e=eabHj9

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data seems to be gathered in one-minute intervals. So it's easy to use count or sum functions to count/sum data from the last 5 rows to arrive at a result for the last 5 minutes. Sum the last 5 rows of the motion index. Sum the last 5 rows of the steps. If these are zero, then the result is "resting". Put that into an IF function.

The exact logic is not quite clear from your descriptions, but you need to start in row 6 with a formula along the lines of

```
=if(and(sum(C2:C6)=0,sum(f2:f6)=0),"Resting",if(D6 > time(0,0,30),"standing",if(E6 > time(0,0,30),"lying","something else")))
```

Copy that formula down.

**Edit after discussion in comments and evaluating sample file:**

If you want to add a sum of the minutes to the condition, then you need to be aware that a sum of five one-minute time values does not add up to the whole number 5. In Excel, 1 is the value for a day and any time value less than one day will be less than 1, i.e. a decimal value.

Even if you don't know what 5 minutes is in decimals  (it is 0.00347222222222222), you can use an Excel function to compare the sum of the five cells with `Time(0,5,0)`, that is, the time value for 0 hours, 5 minutes and 0 seconds.

So, your formula should be changed from using the condition `SUM(D3:D7)=5` to the condition `SUM(D3:D7)=TIME(0,5,0)`.

You are also getting wrong results because the formula sums the 5 values BELOW the current row, instead of ABOVE. You cannot determine if a cow has not moved for 5 minutes if you look into the future.

That's why I wrote above that the formula must start in row 6, because that is the first row where you have five previous entries to evaluate the five previous minutes.

Long story short: start the formula in cell H6 and use

```
=IF(AND(SUM(C2:C6)=0,SUM(F2:F6)=0,SUM(D2:D6)=TIME(0,5,0)),"Resting",IF(E6 > TIME(0,0,30),"lying",IF(D6 > TIME(0,0,30),"standing","Other")))
```

You will not be able to use that formula above row 6, because for these rows you do not have enough data to arrive at a result.

**Second edit after refined logic rules** posted in comment: Adjusted formula that does not only look at the past 5 minutes, but counts each minute in a resting period according to the logic:

> when the animal is standing for 5 consecutive minutes without motion
> or steps, all this 5 minutes have to be considered resting, if the
> animal persist standing without motion or steps it continues to be
> classified as resting. Standing is classified by the animal spending
> more than 30 seconds standing. Lying is classified by the animal
> spending more than 30 seconds lying.

Still needs to start in Row 6, so the previous 5 rows can be evaluated.

```
=IF(
OR(
   AND(SUM(C2:C6)=0,SUM(F2:F6)=0,SUM(D2:D6)=TIME(0,5,0)),
   AND(SUM(C6:C10)=0,SUM(F6:F10)=0,SUM(D6:D10)=TIME(0,5,0))),"Resting",
IF(E6 > TIME(0,0,30),"lying",
IF(D6 > TIME(0,0,30),"standing","Other")))
```

screenshot shows a sample row where lying goes into resting.

[image]

Comment: It worked, but seems that it classified a few lying as standing and some standing as lying. I dont know if I was really clear on what I need. The only behaviour that needs 5 min to be classified is the resting (5 consecutive minutes standing without motion index or steps). The other behaviours have to be classified by minute, if performed for more than 30 seconds.

Comment: I changed the formula suggested to: =IF(AND(SUM(C2:C6)=0,SUM(F2:F6)=0,SUM(D2:D6)=5),"Resting",IF(E2 > TIME(0,0,30),"lying",IF(D2 > TIME(0,0,30),"standing","Other")))

However, the problem now is that it is classifying "resting" as standing. There is anyway to assign priority in excel If function? to prioritize classifying the resting behaviour instead of classifying as standing? Because now he understands if the animal is standing for over 0.30 sec, as standing behaviour, even if it is for 5 consecutive minutes without motion index or steps (Resting)

Comment: The IF statement is evaluated in the order that it is written in. You need to be clear about the logic and the order before you write the IF statement. Can you put it in words, with the precedence clarified? Your formula takes 5 consecutive in column D (standing) and returns "resting". Don't you see that this is the problem?

Comment: I am not sure if I understand your comment. What I need is: if the animal is standing for more than 30 seconds it has to be classified as standing, same thing for lying. However, if the animal stand for 5 consecutive minutes without motion index and steps these 5 minutes have to be classified as resting. Do you understand now?

Comment: So, with the formula you posted in the comment, you say that  "it is classifying "resting" as standing." I'm not sure I understand that. Can you post a data sample and a screenshot for that? The formula will treat data with the last 5 minutes with 0 motion and zero steps AND 5 minutes of standing as "resting". If any one of these three conditions combined with AND is false, then it will look at lying and then at resting.  Have you double checked the sums for their values? Use the Evaluate formula tool to see what the individual conditions return and compare that with your expectations.

Comment: I dont know how to post here a screenshot. So, yes, its classifying as standing, and it make sense because they are above 30 seconds performing this behaviour. However, if spending five minutes (with no motion or steps) it still classifying as standing. It is like it ignored the condition of resting classification.

Comment: Edit your question to post a screenshot (click on the image icon). Because you're new here, the screenshot needs to be made visible by another member. Post a comment with my name and I'll do that. Or post a sample file with a SMALL data sample to an ad-free file sharing service like Onedrive or Dropbox and post the link.

Comment: Hi @teylyn I added the link for the archive with the formula so you can check. I still classifying the resting behaviour as standing, I dont know what do do

Comment: I've edited my answer with an updated formula and an explanation. If that resolved your issue, please mark the answer as described in the tour. If it didn't, please leave a comment, so I can follow up

Comment: So theres no way to classify as resting the  5 minutes before classify as resting? it worked but this is the problem now. If theres is no way to do it I will mark it as solved. Thank you very much for your help

Comment: Also, at 8:47 it has steps and motion index and still classified as behaviour.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you mean. Can you please explain what result you think is wrong and what you think the correct result should be? Use a file with sample data, use the formula I posted. In the file, mark the wrong results, explain the correct results. Then share that file in OneDrive or Dropbox.

Comment: At 8:47, the result is "standing". What should it be instead and why? According to your rules, "standing" is correct, because Motion is greater than zero, so it cannot be "resting". Lying is less than 30 seconds, so it cannot be "Lying"., Standing is greater than 30 seconds, so the result is "standing".

Comment: By the way, you don't need to post 6000 rows of data. A few dozen will be enough. Just make sure that they cover all your possible scenarios.

Comment: https://1drv.ms/x/s!AtN4xlQTB4pPkTQf_mSzpRoyGbeL?e=ShDvrN   here is the archive with your formula and comments about whats wrong with it. (with much less than 6000 data now)

Comment: You did not apply the formula as instructed. You put the formula that should be in **row 6** into row 7. Of course that will get you wrong results. As I wrote in my answer, the formula goes into row 6, summing rows 2 to 6 and looking at the times for row 6.

Comment: still, have you looked at the comment? doesnt matter, still classifying standing before resting as standing, Those 4 standing before resting should be resting.............

Comment: time stamp 8:38: The sum of the last five rows for motion index is greater than 0, so it cannot be "resting". The same goes for time stamps 8:39 to 8:41. Then, at 8:42, the sum of the last five minutes is 0 for motion index, 0 for steps and 5 minutes for standing, so the result is "resting". If this result is wrong, can you please explain what the logic is that leads to the correct result? Because I applied the logic that you set out in your question. 5 consecutive minutes standing with no motion index and no steps is resting. but 8:38 does not meet that condition.

Comment: time stamp 8:47: your comment does not apply after you corrected your wrong application of the formula. The result is "standing" and is correct according to the rules in your question.

Comment: time stamp 9:23 to 9:27: again, the result is "standing" because I applied the rules in your question. Explain why it should be "resting" instead.

Comment: Hi @teylyn, perhaps I dint explain it well. when cattle spent 5 minutes standing, the 5 minutes and any minute more standing without motion index and steps have to be classified as resting. So, for example, from 8:38 to 8:46 all should be resting. Differently if there are less than 5 consecutive minutes standing without motion or steps, it should be standing.

Comment: But at 8:38, the cow has not been standing for more than 5 minutes without motion index and steps. How can that be resting? 8:38 is the first minute of standing after a period of lying. 8:37 has a motion index of 6. So, the first time slot with no motion index in the last 5 minutes will be at 8:42.

Comment: Again, in your question you say: 'If an animal spent 5 minutes standing without motion index or steps I have to classify it as resting,'  time slots 8:38 to 8:41 do not meet the criteria for resting. Please explain why it should be resting?

Comment: After all the effort I put in, providing a solution that does exactly what you asked for, and after spending so much time patiently explaining the approach and correcting your attempts at applying it, I feel it would be polite if you could do the right thing and accept the answer. I don't expect a "thank you", but just acknowledge that this question has an answer.

Comment: If you feel that the question is not answered, then I  again ask you to explain in detail what the rules are that you want to apply to your data and why the results provided by my approach are wrong. If you cannot do that, then please accept the answer.

Comment: "If an animal spent 5 consecutive minutes standing without any motion index or steps I have to classify this behaviour as Resting" What you dont understand from this? seriously, is that difficult? 5 consecutive minutes "standing", without moving, the animal is resting. so all the 5 minutes have to be classified as resting. Cant be that hard to understand. I didnt explain wrongly, you just interpreted in a different way, which was easier for you.

Comment: I understand your point, before the first minute standing there is no other 4 minutes standing to classify it as resting, but the point is that by continuing standing I know that the animal started the resting at that moment @teylyn.

Comment: Can you please, as I have asked multiple times, explain the rules that you ACTUALLY want to apply, because what you wrote in your question is obviously not that, because that's what you have right now and you don't seem to want that. I've given you exactly what you asked for, so now ask for what you actually want.

Comment: look at the comments on the excel file. can be that difficult to understand. If there are 5 conecutive minutes ALL 5 MINUTES HAVE TO BE CONSIDERED RESTING, EVEN BEFORE THE 5TH MINUTE, DO YOU UNDERSTAND? look at the excel file, please

Comment: I am a programmer. I can program the rules that you set out. When you say in your comment "These should be resting too, understand?" -- that is not a rule that I can translate into code or formulas. You have only given the expected result. In order to achieve the expected results, I need to know which logic to apply, so now please write the logic rules that lead to that result.

Comment: rule one: when the animal is standing for  5 consecutive minutes without motion or steps, all this 5 minutes have to be considered resting, if the animal persist standing without motion or steps it continues to be classified as resting. Standing is classified by the animal spending more than  30 seconds standing. Lying is classified by the animal spending more than 30 seconds lying.

Comment: I edited my answer and applied that logic to the formula.